# Silex, in symbollically liked subdirectory, does not route

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing, symlink, silex

I have a Silex project. Works on localhost(using php.exe) but I've just transferred it to a subdirectory of an existing website. For example:

*www.website.foo/silex/*

On the site, because of funky existing routing, the silex app is symbolically linked in the webroot under a */silex/* folder, but is actually elsewhere in the filesystem. **The index page works.**

I wasn't using an .htaccess file, but I copied the one from the documentation, but it hasn't gotten me anywhere.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /var/www/webroot/silex/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I am at a complete loss as to why it doesn't work, let alone what to change to fix it.

*Edited .htaccess*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /silex/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

*Question*
Does the .htaccess file have to be in the root directory? Or is being in the application directory fine?

Comment: Did you make a typo there? `/mblex/` instead of `/silex/` ?

Comment: @Ja͢ck I didn't make a type, I just had originally replaced a project specific string.

Comment: BTW, the .htaccess must be on the silex directory, not root (hence the ```RewriteBase /silex/```)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RewriteBase` directive is wrong, its related to web root, not your filesystem structure, so just use `RewriteBase /silex/`

Comment: Changed it. Still no go. I get a 404 for anything beyond index.php

Comment: Have you read @Jack's question? Did you misstype the ```/mblex/```? If you not, it's time to look at apache logs. Add a ```RewriteLog /path/to/log``` and a ```RewriteLogLevel 5``` directives and access your application to see what file apache tries to call. PS: Assuming apache 2.2, if you're using other version check documentation

Comment: @nobrandheroes, if you need help with logs, update the question with the relevant part of them and we can try to help.